# JSP and Javascript values and method call

Tags: javascript, html-table, jsp-tags

I am developing first JSP application. I have two database tables in MS Access connected with JSP using DSN. What I have to do is very simple. I have a input text box which takes "ID" as input and a Button to view Record. On Button Click, result set will be retrieved from both the tables having records with ID same as input in textbox.

On Button Click, a table should be dynamically created displaying the values retrieved in result set.OnClick Calls a Javascript method ShowData and passes it the values of result set which are placed in dynamic tables.

So form elements' values will be processed after onClick and my result set having records before onClick, as you can see in the code, therefore, I am not able to display correct result as text-input goes null in query and inaccurate result set is achieved.

Please guide me how to properly send text input value to query on ButtonClick Event.

Hope I am clear.

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
            <script  language="javascript">

// creating dynamic tables
                function showData(std_id,std_name,std_prog,std_email,std_semester,std_course,std_status,std_title,std_score,std_credit_hour){

        var width = 25;
        var theader = "<table border='5' id='table1' width = ' "+ width +"% '>";
        var tbody = "";

        var t2header = "<table border='5' id='table2' width = ' "+ width +"% '>";
        var t2body ="";

        tbody += "<tr>";
        tbody += "<td>";
                tbody += "Student ID";
                tbody += "</td>";
                tbody += "<td>";
                tbody += std_id;
         tbody += "</tr>";

         tbody += "<tr>";
        tbody += "<td>";
                tbody += "Student Name";
                tbody += "</td>";
                tbody += "<td>";
                tbody += std_name;
         tbody += "</tr>";

         tbody += "<tr>";
        tbody += "<td>";
                tbody += "Study Program";
                tbody += "</td>";
                tbody += "<td>";
                tbody += std_prog;
         tbody += "</tr>";

         tbody += "<tr>";
        tbody += "<td>";
                tbody += "Email";
                tbody += "</td>";
                tbody += "<td>";
                tbody += std_email;
         tbody += "</tr>";


        t2body += "<tr>";
                t2body += "<td>";
                t2body += "Semester";
                t2body += "</td>";
                t2body += "<td>";
                t2body += "Course";
                t2body += "</td>";
                t2body += "<td>";
                t2body += "Title";
                t2body += "</td>";
                t2body += "<td>";
                t2body += "Status";
                t2body += "</td>";
                t2body += "<td>";
                t2body += "Score";
                t2body += "</td>";
                t2body += "<td>";
                t2body += "Credit Hour";
                t2body += "</td>";
          t2body += "</tr>";


          t2body += "<tr>";
                t2body += "<td>";
                t2body += std_semester;
                t2body += "</td>";
                t2body += "<td>";
                t2body += std_course;
                t2body += "</td>";
                t2body += "<td>";
                t2body +=  std_title;
                t2body += "</td>";
                t2body += "<td>";
                t2body += std_status;
                t2body += "</td>";
                t2body += "<td>";
                t2body += std_score;
                t2body += "</td>";
                t2body += "<td>";
                t2body += std_credit_hour;
                t2body += "</td>";
           t2body += "</tr>";



        var tfooter = "</table>";
        document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter; 
        document.getElementById('new_wrapper').innerHTML = theader + t2body + tfooter;
                }
            </script>
        </head>

        <body>

            <div id="container" style="height:600px;width:700px;border:#6666ff; border-style: solid;background-color: aliceblue" >


     <div id='content' style='height:330px;width: 550px;text-align: left;background-color: #F3F3F3;float: left;border:#6666ff'>
      <h3>Enter Student ID to View Grade Book Information</h3>
              <form  id="myform" action="viewGradeBook.jsp" method="POST" >
            Enter Student ID &nbsp;<input type="text" name="View_Std_Id" value="" /> // it need to be sent to query
            <br/>

             <%     
                String id_input = request.getParameter("View_Std_Id");
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String conUrl = "jdbc:odbc:GradeBookDSN";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl);
    String sql = " SELECT * FROM StudentProfile , GradeBook WHERE StudentProfile.StudentID AND GradeBook.StudentID = '"+id_input+"' ";

    PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
                String id= "";
                String name="";
                 String prog="";
                 String email ="";
                 String semester = "";
                String course = "";
                 String status = "";
                 String title = "";
                 String score = "";
                 String credit_hour = "";
    while(rs.next()){
    // The row name is ―name‖ in database ―PersonInfo,// hence specified in the getString() method.
    id = rs.getString("StudentID");
     name = rs.getString("StudentName");
    prog = rs.getString("StudyProgram");
    email = rs.getString("Email");
     semester = rs.getString("Semester");
     course = rs.getString("Course");
      status = rs.getString("Status");
      title = rs.getString("Title");
      score = rs.getString("Score");
     credit_hour = rs.getString("CreditHour");

    }

           %>

            <input type="button" value="View Record" onclick="showData(.......)"/>

            <div id="wrapper"></div>
            <br/>
            <div id="new_wrapper"></div>
            </form>





 </div>

<div id='footer' style="background-color: #C2D5FC;clear: both;text-align: center;border:#6666ff">Copyrights@vu2014</div>  
</div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: as you are having just one jsp, try using GET method in form instead of POST method.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to acheive this in a single JSP load.

The JSP is a view that is evaluated and rendered on a single web request (a request correspond to the loading of your web page)

If you click on a button you will then you are already on the client side and you don't have access to the database which is on the server side.

You have to generate a second request (for example, instead of a button you put a submit and you put it inside a form) and you pass parameters to this request to allow the server to execute the SQL query.

With this approach you won't need to inject some html in javascript.

You should read more about N-tier architecture, servlets and the MVC model.

The good practice is to have :

- a servlet (controller) that do the treatment (your sql query) and generates one or more beans.
- the java beans (model) that contains the data to be displayed
- the JSP (the view) that only displays the html with the dynamic values contained in the view

This structure will help you to

- understand what happens really in a web application.
- deal with exceptions (your database access is not well coded, you have to manage exceptions and close the connection in a finally block)
- test your treatments without the graphical issues.

you can try this link as a start
http://rathinasaba.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/simple-webapplication-using-servlet-and-jsp/

Comment: OK, Thanks alot. But how will I come back to this jsp for displaying the dynamic table below the input textBox and Button, having values of the result set ?

Comment: You have to realize that you cannot jump into J2EE without reading the doc more precisely and probably follow an entire tutorial. Once you have executed a servlet you render the jsp you want with the forward mechanism. 

In the exemple I gave you, you can see the calls to request.getRequestDispatcher() and dispatcher.forward().